# mapbox: How to get light default map?

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox

Currently, I have developing angular app which has map box integrated, I have followed the mapbox instructions but unable to get the desired output.[image]

Can someone guide me that how to achieve following map?

```
 <div class="row">
<mgl-map
    renderWorldCopies="false"
    [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10'"
    [zoom]="[0]"
    [center]="center"
>
    <mgl-image
        id="blue"
        url="../../../../../assets/images/blue.png"
        (loaded)="imageLoaded = 'true'"
    >
    </mgl-image>
    <mgl-image
        id="red"
        url="../../../../../assets/images/red.png"
        (loaded)="imageLoaded = 'true'"
    >
    </mgl-image>
    </mgl-image>
    <mgl-geojson-source
        id="points"
        [data]="countryCoordinatesList"
    ></mgl-geojson-source>
    <ng-container *ngIf="imageLoaded">
        <mgl-layer
            (click)="onClick(row)"
            *ngFor="let row of countryList"
            [id]="toStringNum(row?.properties?.id)"
            type="symbol"
            [source]="{
                type: 'geojson',
                data: {
                    type: 'Feature',
                    geometry: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [
                            row.geometry.coordinates[0],
                            row.geometry.coordinates[1]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }"
            [layout]="{
                'icon-image': row.properties.icon,
                'icon-size': 0.4,
                'icon-allow-overlap': true
            }"
        ></mgl-layer>
    </ng-container>
    <mgl-layer
        id="points"
        source="points"
        type="symbol"
        [layout]=""
    ></mgl-layer>
</mgl-map>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To make your map look exactly like yours, you would have to modify the style a bit, however using this style

`mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10`

the below code should give you a map somewhat similar to what you showed. You would have to change the position of the markers and the marker image to match yours.

Also. please make sure to replace <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN> by your token.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Draw GeoJSON points</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: [-96, 37.8],
        zoom: 3
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
        // Add an image to use as a custom marker
        map.loadImage(
            'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
            function (error, image) {
                if (error) throw error;
                map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
                // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
                map.addSource('points', {
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                        'features': [
                            {
                                // feature for Mapbox DC
                                'type': 'Feature',
                                'geometry': {
                                    'type': 'Point',
                                    'coordinates': [
                                        -77.03238901390978,
                                        38.913188059745586
                                    ]
                                },
                                'properties': {
                                    'title': 'Mapbox DC'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                // feature for Mapbox SF
                                'type': 'Feature',
                                'geometry': {
                                    'type': 'Point',
                                    'coordinates': [-122.414, 37.776]
                                },
                                'properties': {
                                    'title': 'Mapbox SF'
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });

                // Add a symbol layer
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'points',
                    'type': 'symbol',
                    'source': 'points',
                    'layout': {
                        'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
                        // get the title name from the source's "title" property
                        'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
                        'text-font': [
                            'Open Sans Semibold',
                            'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
                        ],
                        'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
                        'text-anchor': 'top'
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```